# How to count no of rows in Google Spreadsheet and check if it contains a emailId value in the required column

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Cant work out how to count the number of rows that have an email address in them, to populate the number of rows to process. I have a spreadsheet with a list of emails, the number of emailable rows changes regularly, so I'd like to count emailable rows, and instead of manually typing "28" or whatever, I'd like it to automatically find that number :)

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 28;  // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = "membership number"
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns the current number of rows in the sheet, regardless of content.

```
var emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

var noOfRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, noOfRows , 4)
var data = dataRange.getValues();
data.foreach((row)=>{
  if(emailRegex.test(row[0])){
    var emailAddress = row[0];
    var message = row[1];
    var subject = "membership number"
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
});
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow%28%29

Comment: Thanks pal, this would be great, however the first column has an index/match function, so it says NA for a couple of hundred rows. So, I'd like to get the number of rows with an email address in it.

Answer (score 0):

for counting email addresses in a range you can use simply:

```
=COUNTIF(A:C, "*@*")
```

or the proper way:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(ISEMAIL(A:C), TRUE))
```